# asp.net mvc add local file to web server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, http, url

I'm working on a ASP.Net MVC application. In my project, I have a third party JavaScript library which dynamically saves data in a xml format. Using some C# server code, I read this xml data and save it to a local file on my computer.

I will then need to load this said data using the same JavaScript library as before. The library has a load function which, will load xml data from a http URL (cannot give it a local file path)

My question is how do place my file on a local server, so I may call an http URL of the file?

Here is the question I had posted on the third party tool's forum:

http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=37252&p=115601#p115601

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

the javascript function:

```
scheduler.load("http://localhost/Tasks.xml", "xml");
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't read a file directly from javascript for security reasons. Browsers shouldn't let you access a file directly from disk.

You can put the file inside an IIS or other web server and access the URL.

```
For example: copy the file to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\YourFile.xml

Access from http://localhost:80/YourFile.xml
```

Test in a web browser before you test from the API to make sure that the file is accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Ill go about putting my file in an IIS server of some sort. I've never done this before, so i'll have to do some research, unless you can provide an simple example/direction to follow. Thanks!

Comment: It's very straightforward. Check if IIS is installed in your machine (turning Windows Features on/off) and if it is installed, the directories I've provided are the defaults.

Comment: So I have enabled IIS and have placed the file accordingly.
When i click the file, the url still shows C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Tasks.xml

Tried with the API for fun, didn't work. I posted a picture of the FireBug console.

Comment: Can you access the URL from a browser, directly (outside javascript)?

Comment: Use the http:// and correct slashes (/) not backslashes (\). Sounds like your problem is that the URL is malformed

Comment: even after putting http:// localhost/Tasks.xml (no space after the second slash, needed to put space, so i can you the string without it being a link.) as the URL, still no results, same firebug console as before.

Comment: you should use the http:// as a prefix in the URL. In my previous commit, stackoverflow removed the prefix to transform the URL in a link :-(

Answer (score 1):

You should create a controller action that reads the local file and returns it, after appropriate security checks. Then in your Javascript you use the URL of the controller/action.

The proper place to save files in a web application is inside the `App_Data` directory. If you update files anywhere else in the web application's directory it will cause a restart of the site (and an app pool recycle).